# Import path relative to constant

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In PHP I can define a constant relative to my entrypoint file and then use it in any file to include files relative to that path.

index.php

```
define('APP', getcwd());
```

some/deeply/nested/path.php

```
include APP.'/libs/someLib.php';
```

I'd like to do a similar thing in javascript, but can't seem to accomplish it. Ideally code like this would work. But it seems like the import can only take string literals.

index.html

```
const APP = window.location.pathname;
```

some/deeply/nested/path.js

```
import APP+'/libs/someLib.js';
```

Is there a way to do this without littering my code with long relative paths (../../../../)?

Comment: No, ES6 imports must be static strings, they can't be dynamically computed expressions. You can however tell your module bundler how to resolve paths.

Comment: That's unfortunate, I'm not using a bundler, just regular javascript.